# Get actual return type from a Expression<Func<T, object>> instance

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees

I have a method that accepts a `Expression<Func<T, object>>` instance. I want to get at the *actual* data type being returned by a specific expression instance, rather than `object`.

I can get it to work for direct property references, so if I pass in the expression `x => x.IntegerProperty` I can get a Type reference for an integer. This approach requires converting it to a MemberExpression.

However, I can't get it to work for arbitrary expressions. For instance, if the expression is `x => x.IntegerProperty.ToString()` I want to get a Type reference for a string. I can't compile this to a MemberExpression, and if I just `.Compile()` it and check the return type I get "object".

How can I look at the specific expression instance and derive the actual return type?

Comment: Technically, the actual return type of the expression is... `object`.  Since the function was required to return `object`, the necessary expressions were generated to ensure that it is the type returned (a conversion in this case).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Something like this might do the trick. It probably doesn't cover every possibility, but it's a start.

```
public static Type GetObjectType<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
{
    if ((expr.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert) ||
        (expr.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.ConvertChecked))
    {
        var unary = expr.Body as UnaryExpression;
        if (unary != null)
            return unary.Operand.Type;
    }
    return expr.Body.Type;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't think of any other expression types that this could possibly be if it wasn't actually `object`.  Covers all the cases that I could think of.

Comment: Worked great. I'm using this in a pretty specific set of circumstances, so if there _are_ edge cases that you haven't covered they aren't causing me any pain yet. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't expr.Body.Type enough? I get wrong result when using the code above with for instance i => (float)i where i is an integer. Then this code returns integer and not float. But simply expr.Body.Type works.

Comment: @Andreas: Are you sure? My code above correctly returns `float` when I pass in `(int i) => (float)i`, whereas using just `expr.Body.Type` returns `object`.

Answer (score 3):

While not impossible, this is particularly difficult. It would require walking the expression tree and doing some potentially complex logic. For example, what would you want to see if I passed in the following expression?

```
Func<bool, object> expr = switch => switch ? 1 : "False";
```

This method *could* either return an `int` or a `string`.

Now, you might be able to make more headway by offloading some of this logic on the compiler. You could change your method parameter from `Func<T, object>` to `Func<T, TReturn>` and use `typeof(TReturn)` within the method to determine what the compiler decided the return type of the expression was.

Of course, in the case of my example, you'll still be working against `object`. But, your example of `x => x.IntegerProperty.ToString()` will yield `string`, which is what you're looking for.

Comment: You make some good points, but this is being used in some specific circumstances where those edge cases shouldn't come up (or can be easily avoided by knowing about them). Thanks!

Comment: Actually, @Adam Maras, your example would never even compile because the ternary operator would throw a  compile time error saying "Type of conditional expression can not be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and 'string' "

Comment: It was more of a thought exercise than a literal code sample.

Answer (score -2):

Bit of a cheeky way (and it involves actually invoking the `Func`), but you can do this:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static Func<T,object> MakeFunc<T>()
    {
        return x => 23;
    }

    static Type GetReturnType<T>(Func<T,object> f)
    {
        return f(default(T)).GetType();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type t = GetReturnType(MakeFunc<string>());
        Console.WriteLine(t);
    }
}
```

It's not guaranteed to work in all situations, I should add - particularly if the `default(T)` isn't a valid parameter to the `Func`. But it's a potential starting point at least.

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about executing the expression to get the return type; what if there are side effects to the function? In my specific case that isn't a big worry, but I accepted an answer that seems to work just as well and doesn't require execution. Thanks though!

Comment: @Seth: Personally I wouldn't be too happy about executing the expression (it's a limitation of the approach) - it was just the best I could come up with off the top of my head. The one advantage of this approach is that it works on `Func` instances rather than `Expression` instances.