# EF Expression<Func<T, object>> Properties Detection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression

I want to get some info about 'Expression'.

There are two class:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Image Photo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Image> UserGallery { get; set; }
}
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Expression<Func<User, object>> ex1 = c => c.Name,
        ex2 = c => c.Photo,
        ex3 = c => c.UserGallery;
        DetectPropertyType(ex1);//i want to print: 'scalar'
        DetectPropertyType(ex2);//i want to print: 'related'
        DetectPropertyType(ex3);//i want to print: 'collection'

    }
    public static void DetectPropertyType(Expression<Func<User, object>> expression)
    {
        //How to detect kind of 'expression'
        //my question here
    }
```

I want to detect because when I want `Update` an `Object` that have a Reference; I will use handle it with another code.

> OK

```
myContext.Entry(AttachedObject).Property(ex1).IsModified = true;
```

---

> Error: The property 'Photo' on type 'User' is not a primitive or
>   complex property. The Property method can only be used with primitive
>   or complex properties. Use the Reference or Collection method.

```
myContext.Entry(AttachedObject).Property(ex2).IsModified = true;
```

---

> Error

```
myContext.Entry(AttachedObject).Property(ex3).IsModified = true;
```

Comment: I think you literally have to do what it says, use `Reference`, or `Collection` instead of `Property`.  Like this `myContext.Entry(AttachedObject).Reference(ex3).IsModified = true;`.  `Reference` is only for simple properties, `Reference` deals with single navigation properties, `Collection` deals with sets.

Comment: yes i know, but first need to detect

Comment: Entry(obj).Reference(ex3).EntityEntry.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

Comment: Ahh, I see, you want to be able to programatically tell if you need to use `Property`, `Reference`, or `Collection`?  If so, you should update your question to be a little more clear.  I'll see if I can find any information how how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to determine if the return type of the expression is a reference or not. So using code form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055368/1663001):

```
public static Type GetObjectType<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
{
    if ((expr.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert) ||
        (expr.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.ConvertChecked))
    {
        var unary = expr.Body as UnaryExpression;
        if (unary != null)
            return unary.Operand.Type;
    }
    return expr.Body.Type;
}
```

You can do this:

```
var returnType = GetObjectType(e1);

if(typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(returnType))
{
    myContext.Entry(AttachedObject).Collection(ex1).IsModified = true;
}
else if(returnType.IsClass && !typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(returnType)) 
{
    myContext.Entry(AttachedObject).Reference(ex1).IsModified = true;
}
else
{
    myContext.Entry(AttachedObject).Property(ex1).IsModified = true;
}
```

Comment: Assuming he could also check for `Collection` by checking to see if it implements `IEnumerable`?

Comment: dosen't work. for `c => c.Name` `returnType.IsClass` returns `true`