# How to detect actual type of an expression result?

Tags: c#, lambda

I need to pass a dictionary of property mapping expressions to my function. For example the following map may be passed:

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, object>>>
{
    {"ID", original => original.ID },                         // int
    {"Name", original => original.User.Name },                // string
    {"Timestamp", original => original.Modified },            // DateTime
    {"Cost", original => original.Price * original.Quantity } // Double
};
```

As you can see the returned types are different, therefore I use `object` in the delegate definitions. Inside the function I need to handle the expressions in dependence on actual returned type, so I have to detect the types.

```
public static IQueryable<T> MyFunction<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IDictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, object>>> map)
{
    foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> transform in map.Values)
    {
        Type type = transform.ReturnType;
        // do something in dependense of detected type
    }
}
```

Of course, the `type` is always `object`. Is there way to pass a dictionary of expressions and then detect actual type of each expression result without the expression invoke?

Comment: How about this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055368/1099716

Comment: @AccessDenied, I was looking for the solution 3 days, but could not find! You are my hero! Thank you very much!!!